# Collapsing Legend in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I am using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.UWP for creating charts in a UWP application using Visual Studio.  I am trying to hide the legends using Visibility="Collapsed".  It removed the legend in the design view but not at run time.  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I could get rid of it by removing `Legend` from the `Chart` template. The `Visibility` of the `Legend` element is bound to its `ContentVisibility` that seems to be controlled from the inside. If you need to change the visibility at runtime - you could try wrapping the `Legend` element with a `Grid` and control the `Visibility` of that `Grid` instead.